# cordova-android build with conflicting android component/dependency versions (play-services-location, firebase etc.)

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, google-play-services

When building android through Cordova, different plugins/dependencies require different versions of Android components, and the only way to make the build work is to use android studio to help correct the version numbers.

Is there a Cordova build in way to configure the component versions across plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to configure it directly in Cordova.

This gist shows a way to use an external Gradle config to force the version numbers, which works:
https://gist.github.com/ulrichenslin/9cf52a0f140bddf5554dc69a34a81737

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: This, your own question,  would be a good place to elaborate on the solution you found. Keep in mind that StackOverflow wants the solutions here (where you grant them the rights to them). StackOverflow is not meant to provide you an advertisment platform for your own content.